# Health related kanji compound: 了承群

Tags: kanji

I'm currently trying to plug my way through a Japanese article about end-of-life care for the elderly. So far I'm getting the jist, but one compound has stumped me. Here's the full sentence:

> 回答者を看取り介護**了承群**、迷い群、未**了承群**の3群に分け、入居者の「認知力」、「活動力」、施設の「介護力」、家族の「生き方」と「死への向きあい方」について比較した結果、**了承群**>迷い群>未了承群の順で入居者の認知力は低く、施設の介護力への評価が高かった。

The sentence is talking about the results of a self-administered questionnaire, but yeah...I have no idea about the compound, and google searches are just leading me to Chinese webpages, which aren't helpful. I've tried breaking down each character, so far I have that 了 means "complete" and 群 "group" but I'm not sure if this is accurate, and obviously when compounds are put together the meaning can shift a bit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue here is not 了承群.  The clue is just after that part:  `の３群に分け`.  Now re-read the beginning and attempt to make sense of it.

> The respondents/"answerers"/survey participants split into three 群 (crowds/groups): (the group of) those that consent to giving care, (the group of) those that were lost on it, and (the group of) those who had yet to give consent...

So the 群 is just a suffix to represent each of the 3 groups.  It's not inherently part of the term 了承 (which is itself not inherently a health related term).  I would assume a pronunciation of 「ぐん」 for it; someone can correct me if it would actually be 「むれ」.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that completely makes sense to me now.

Comment: +1 The pronunciation is definitely ぐん.